# MassTransit with RabbitMQ Cluster connecting issue

Tags: c#, cluster-computing, rabbitmq, masstransit

I ran into this problem thought maybe someone can help me out.

So I added one cluster node to my RabbitMQ server.
Now I want to connect to the server on my client. I want MassTransit to connect to the first available server just like RabbitMQ.Client that you can pass an array of endpoints and it will connect to the first available.

Thanks,
Peyman

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that this is currently supported.
[RabbitMqTransportFactory](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/Transports/MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq/RabbitMqTransportFactory.cs)

It may not be relevant, but we are using clustering as well. Each of our machines that host a client (message sender and receiver) is also a Rabbit Node in the HA Cluster. So the client only ever talks to localhost. This makes config easier and no network hops.

Comment: If you have a lot of nodes (on every client), this is not performant I would guess, because reasons of replication?